# Jmeter contains string match

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to use contains instead of == in jmeter?

Eg:
$.employees[?(@.lastName == 'Smith')].firstName

I would like to use contains 'Smith'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `=~` operator which returns the node(s) which match the regular expression.

So if you amend your query to be something like:

```
$.employees[?(@.lastName =~ /.*smith.*?/i)].firstName
```

it will return first names of the employees where lastName contains `smith` anywhere and it will be case-insensitive.

More information:

- [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri. I really appreciate your contribution to the community.